# Add date and time to footnote graph of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I am running a loop all day and during its execution, it saves different graphs. I need to include or add the time in the  graph bottom, footnote or even subtitle.

I am Working with ggplot. Here is a basic example of how my code is structured:

```
{p <- ggplot(subset(dm, freq>300),aes(word, freq)) }
{p}
{print(p)}
{dev.off()}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use ggplot + labs(caption = "footnote"). See example below using mtcars.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg))+ geom_point() + labs(caption = paste(Sys.time()))
```